# Run-Time Error 424 when copying sheets

Tags: excel, vba

My apologies up front as I am new to vba code.  I am having an issue with the following code.  I am trying to open a file then copy all the sheets from that file to the current workbook.  It currently returns the run-time error 424

```
Private Sub testGetFile()

Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Application.GetOpenFilename

For Each sh In wb2
sh.Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `GetOpenFilename` correctly. Since it's not a `Workbook` object, you cannot set it directly to a workbook.

There are a couple other places in the code I cleaned up too.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub testGetFile()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

    Dim fileToOpen As Variant
    fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename

    If fileToOpen = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim wb2 As Workbook
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fileToOpen)
    End If

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In wb2.Worksheets
        sh.Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I receive a compile error: Syntax error on: If fileToOpen= False

Comment: I added "Then"  to line and corrected issue: If fileToOpen = False Then
    Exit Sub
Else

Comment: I had to add Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook Dim sh As Worksheet Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook to resolve variable not defined error. But I think I am still doing something wrong with setting wb2 as workbook. Nothing is copied from wb2 to wb1 and no errors are reported via "F5". But if I "F8" I receive a run-time error 438 on line For Each sh In wb2????

Comment: Just a note I have Option Explicit in this module

Comment: @VBANewbie - I repeat. Please make sure you copy my edited code. I have tested and verified the code. Copy exactly as is and try again.

Comment: Thanks so much.  It now works.  I really appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`wb2` is a workbook and `GetOpenFilename` returns a `String`. E.g., you have to take the returned String and to use it to set it as a `wb2`:

```
Dim fileName    As String
fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Workbooks.Open fileName
```

[GetOpenFilename MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.GetOpenFilename)